# Under investigation, under consideration, under evaluation or none of them

Tags: word-choice

I'm seeking for a way to express some idea  and I have shown three of my guesses, but I am not sure if any of them is correct or not. If none of them is correct, please suggest to me an expression with similar format, that is, "under + sth".

Some additional information: An experiment is done using a composite plate. Then I want to express the plate and give some info regarding its specifications. For this, I'm going to use a sentence with similar format as the examples below.

- The plate under consideration  contains three types of defects.
- The plate under evaluation contains three types of defects.
- The plate under investigation contains three types of defects.
- The plate under examination contains three types of defects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This depends on the context in which you find this sentence; no context, no possible conclusion. Please, add the context to your question.

Comment: Are you considering it (thinking about using it), evaluating it (deciding whether it is suitable) or investigating it (finding out about it)?

Comment: @KateBunting You said finding out about it. Does it matter what type of information I'm trying to find out about it?

Comment: @LPH I added some additional info. Thanks.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. NB It's _under examination_, not _under examine_.

Comment: @KateBunting Many thanks. I had also used under investigation, however; the professor editing it believed that investigation should solely be used to state things related to crime. I had another search in Longman now and it's said that we can use it for scientific problems as well. Again many thanks.

Comment: Considering the plate means deciding to use it or not, but that's already decided. You are investigating the composite in general, not really the plate, but that's not the activity of the moment.  Testing and judging fit the remaining choices.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Many thanks.

Comment: It's the use of *investigation* **with *under*** that triggers a crime interpretation. All of your sentences would probably work, and work better, if you used a passive/past participle form: *the plate considered*, *the plate evaluated*, *the plate investigated*, *the plate examined*...

Comment: *Investigation*, *examination*, and perhaps also *evaluation*, tend to suggest a process that is relatively formal and structured, while 'the plate under consideration' needn't mean anything more than 'the plate we are talking about here'. Apart from that, the choice is a mater of style, unless some of these words function as technical terms in the relevant field.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Thanks for providing the detailed answer

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would have constructed the sentences this way

```
The plate under consideration contains three types of defects.

The plate under (or 'undergoing') evaluation contains three types of defects.

The plate under investigation contains three types of defects.

The plate under (or 'undergoing') examination contains three types of defects.
```

Or

```
The plate being considered has three types of defects.

The plate being evaluated has three types of defects.

The plate being investigated has three types of defects.

The plate being examined has three types of defects.
```

*"Consideration"* may be better used for a final or preliminary approval/disapproval process.

*"Evaluation"* may be better used for suitability ascertainment process: if not suitable for this, is it suitable for that?

*"Examination"* may be better used for rigorous, methodical evaluation or scrutiny.

*"Investigation"* may be better used when the process is a rigorous, methodical 'fault finding mission' or 'new property discovering mission'.

Comment: Seemingly, under investigation suits more to what I wanna express. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Never lock yourself into the straight-jacket of a predetermined linguistic structure. Science and technology is best communicated in plain English, especially given the unavoidable technical terms. Are you sure that you cannot write this?

> **This** plate contains…

Comment: Of course, I can use this in place of what I wrote in the question, but wanted to know whether any of them is correct or not. More specifically, this example is not the only place that I wanna use such a structure and therefore knowing if any of them is correct or not can be beneficial for me. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ErfanBrv  I may have said this already, but I really think questions of this type can generally answered by simple search techniques that scientists should be familiar with. Failing that, imho they are better posted on English Language Learners. Personally when I have to translate into French, German or Italian I take my phrase and use it as a general Google search term or try it in a Google Books ngram search. I then look carefully at the context of the results. Another way of looking for phrases in context is Wikipedia articles on the topic of interest, but in the target language.

Comment: Thank you David for your suggestion. Before asking this question, I'd searched by putting the word inside "". The result, however, wasn't clear enough for me and I was still in doubt. So, decided to ask it here in order that I can see what the opinions of native people are. Sometimes, I get good advise here. For example, I was familiar with Google books ngram but didn't know that it is possible to do the same thing in Wikipedia articles. I will certainly use  your advise. Many thanks